# Is it possible to mount versioned part of a monorepo in a container?

Tags: git, docker-compose

I work with a monorepo hosting every project of the company with a tree like this:

```
Repo :
  - apps/
    - api_1/
      - app/
      - bin/
      - lib/
      - spec/
      - dockerfile
      - compose.yml
    - api_2/
      - app/
      - bin/
      - lib/
      - spec/
      - dockerfile
      - compose.yml
    - config/
      - files.json
      - schema.yml
      - ...
  - infra/
  - scripts/
  - .git
  - ...
```

I would like to work on my container, no problem here but, I would like to also have versioning and there is the catch.
My `compose.yml` of each apis mount only the api they need and not all the others to not have a container containing everything on the earth.

Is there any possibility to susbet the folder mounted in the container to be able t use git capabilities in the container ?

My idea was to simply mount the `.git` folder of the root in my containers, but with only few folders, I have a awfull diff with everything deleted which is normal.

I tried to use git sparse-checkout but didn't fully understand how to use it
I tried to find if there is a way to do a git clone of only a subfolder of a repo but didn't find any way

Edit: An other constraint, I use the same Dockerfile / `entrypoint.sh` for each api, for now, they are mounted in /usr/local/app. So, I also need to rename or symlink the contained folder

Comment: Consider how `git sparse-checkout` can help you.

Comment: It seems indeed to help but I have an another constraint. I use the same entrypoint.sh for every api, so in my container, api folders are named app and my entrypoint hit on that folder
I can't mix some kind of renaming or sym link with all that